# how to send data on c++ serialport in Qt Widget

Tags: c++, qtserialport, flashing

i want make samsung flasher simillar to odin flasher for flash rom (package of system data) with qt widget.

i need c++ command on port for flashing data to device and how to connect program to device for this operation.

Comment: And your *specific* question/problem is what? We are not going to write code for you or point you at a third party tool. You need to show us what you've tried so far and where you've failed and then we can maybe help you fix whatever problems you are having.

Comment: i want to start for make this program for flashing. how i can begin? where i can found a document about it?!

Comment: No idea. Have you asked Google?

Comment: yes. but i can't find useful thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use library at [qtserial library](http://qextserialport.github.io/). Here is the sample snippet to get uart working.

```
QextSerialPort port;
port.setPortName("portName");
port.setBaudRate(BAUD115200);
port.setFlowControl(FLOW_OFF);
port.setParity(PAR_NONE);
port.setDataBits(DATA_8);
port.setStopBits(STOP_1);
port.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

For reading data from UART.

```
char ch;
port.getChar(&ch))
```

Comment: I hope answer will be useful to you.

Comment: thnx for answer. important problem is how send samsung system data to device with this library function. for example i want flash boot.img on samsung device, how can do this operation with this library?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an almost complete code, to connect and send data, with a serial connection:

.h file:

```
private slots:

    void connectSerial();
    void sendData();
    void closeSerial();
...
```

.cpp file:

```
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>

static QSerialPort * serialPort;
...
```

Connect to Serial:

```
void MainWindow::connectSerial()
{
    serialPort = new QSerialPort;
    serialPort->setPortName("com1");
    serialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    serialPort->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    serialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serialPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    QObject::connect(serialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readSerial()));
}
...
```

Read data send from the device:

```
void MainWindow::readSerial()
{
    ....
}
```

Send QString data (12345), to Serial:

```
void MainWindow::sendData()
{
    QByteArray payload_buffer;
    QString Data = "12345";
    payload_buffer = payload_buffer.append(Data.toLatin1());
    if(serialPort->isWritable()){
        serialPort->write(payload_buffer,(payload_buffer.size()));
    }
}
...
```

Remember to close the connecting!:

```
void MainWindow::closeSerial()
{
    serialPort->close();
}
...
```

[qserialport](/questions/tagged/qserialport) [qt](/questions/tagged/qt)